# Modificación de un objeto objeto en base a dos propiedades javascript

Tags: javascript

LLevo varios dias atascado con la modificación de un array de objetos, para su posterior representación en una gráfica Highcharts.

El array de objetos es el siguientes, no os pongo todos los objetos del array puesto que son muchos.

```
0: {fecha: 1433109600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 49.73698235772901}
1: {fecha: 1433109600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 60.49376144058218}
2: {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 28.505397876893902}
3: {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 74.91340610529366}
4: {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.71794096159791}
5: {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 23.395346314392796}
6: {fecha: 1433196000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 31.881330330646218}
7: {fecha: 1433196000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 87.31637095133911}
8: {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 46.300059172697175}
9: {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 38.82816133242129}
10: {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 28.03958217326741}
11: {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 59.82886035213437}
12: {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 11.327755968034303}
13: {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 6.400865852071913}
14: {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 67.31913706183693}
15: {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 92.60614675663679}
16: {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.508066001283076}
17: {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 72.27499816403673}
18: {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 57.48997225382926}
19: {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 57.40345634882333}
20: {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 70.70814308763902}
21: {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 0.3253988527121887}
22: {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.18931560611268}
23: {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 96.61915450438259}
24: {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 77.88148521586558}
25: {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 92.83072335206866}
26: {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 63.8569758442417}
27: {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 11.889180738447624}
28: {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 28.32219302898853}
29: {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 68.05799731426629}
30: {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 74.49832916690504}
31: {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 98.32817378920366}
32: {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 91.47337644564648}
33: {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 31.273994175467166}
34: {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 49.07981716102785}
35: {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 74.10101967551246}
36: {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 40.86583930566705}
37: {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 75.10236610849115}
38: {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 92.7916625879253}
39: {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 35.42493446978297}
40: {fecha: 1433894400000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 94.65211432925513}
```

Como veis hay objetos que tienen misma fecha y categoría y otros no.
Lo que quiero es un objeto resultante en el que los objetos que tengan misma fecha y categoría se sume su valor (que se "unifiquen" en único elemento) y los que no cumplan esta condición que permanezcan como están.

Y este es el código utilizado

```
let nuevoArray =  arrayGraficaOrdenada
                  .map((el, i, self) => {
                    const existences = self.filter(obj => obj.fecha === el.fecha);
                    const existencesCat = self.filter(obj => obj.categoria === el.categoria);
                    if (existences.length > 1) {
                      const $el = Object.assign({}, el, {
                       valor: existencesCat.map(obj => obj.valor)
                               .reduce((a,b)=> a+b,0)
                      });
                      return $el;
                    }
                  })
                  .filter((el, i, self) => el)
                  .filter((el, i, self) => (
                    self.findIndex($el => $el.fecha === el.fecha) === i)               
                  );
```

Comment: y que has probado?

Comment: De donde sacas la informacion? De una base de datos?

Comment: te podemos ayudar pero necesitamos algo de lo que haz hecho

Comment: Si la información la obtienes de una base de datos es mucho mejor y eficiente agrupar los datos desde ahí.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar hacerlo con este algoritmo, el cual usa un hash para almacenar los valores, por lo tanto solo se itera dos veces, uno al arreglo original de datos y otro a un arreglo de igual o menor tamaño al arreglo original.

**Nota:** Si los datos los obtienes de una base de datos es mucho mejor y eficiente agrupar los datos desde ahí.

```
let data =  [{fecha: 1433109600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 49.73698235772901},
        {fecha: 1433109600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 60.49376144058218},
        {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 28.505397876893902},
        {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 74.91340610529366},
        {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.71794096159791},
        {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 23.395346314392796},
        {fecha: 1433196000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 31.881330330646218},
        {fecha: 1433196000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 87.31637095133911},
        {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 46.300059172697175},
        {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 38.82816133242129},
        {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 28.03958217326741},
        {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 59.82886035213437},
        {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 11.327755968034303},
        {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 6.400865852071913},
        {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 67.31913706183693},
        {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 92.60614675663679},
        {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.508066001283076},
        {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 72.27499816403673},
        {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 57.48997225382926},
        {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 57.40345634882333},
        {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 70.70814308763902},
        {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 0.3253988527121887},
        {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.18931560611268},
        {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 96.61915450438259},
        {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 77.88148521586558},
        {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 92.83072335206866},
        {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 63.8569758442417},
        {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 11.889180738447624},
        {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 28.32219302898853},
        {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 68.05799731426629},
        {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 74.49832916690504},
        {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 98.32817378920366},
        {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 91.47337644564648},
        {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 31.273994175467166},
        {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 49.07981716102785},
        {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 74.10101967551246},
        {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 40.86583930566705},
        {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 75.10236610849115},
        {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 92.7916625879253},
        {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 35.42493446978297},
        {fecha: 1433894400000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 94.65211432925513}]
    ;

    let tempHash = {};

    // Recorrer el arreglo y acumular el valor en un hash en las cuales las keys son fecha-categoria
    data.forEach(function(item, index) {
        let tempKey = `${item.fecha}-${item.categoria}`;
        if (tempHash[tempKey]) {
            tempHash[tempKey] += item.valor;
        } else {
            tempHash[tempKey] = item.valor;
        }
    });

    let newData = [];

    // recorrer las keys del hash
    Object.keys(tempHash).forEach(function(item, index) {
        // obtener el valor que se acumuló en tempHash
        let value = tempHash[item];
        let keys = item.split('-'); // Separar la key en la fecha y categoria
        let date = keys[0];
        let category = keys[1];
        // agregar el elemento al nuevo arreglo de datos
        newData.push({
            fecha: date,
            categoria: category,
            valor: value
        });

    });

    // Imprimir en consola los datos ya acumulados y sin repeticiones
    console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Est es mi solución:

```js
let elarray = [
  { fecha: 1433109600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 49.73698235772901 },
  { fecha: 1433109600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 60.49376144058218 },
  { fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 28.505397876893902 },
  { fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 74.91340610529366 },
  { fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.71794096159791 },
  { fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 23.395346314392796 },
  { fecha: 1433196000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 31.881330330646218 },
  { fecha: 1433196000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 87.31637095133911 },
  { fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 46.300059172697175 },
  { fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 38.82816133242129 },
  { fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 28.03958217326741 },
  { fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 59.82886035213437 },
  { fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 11.327755968034303 },
  { fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 6.400865852071913 },
  { fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 67.31913706183693 },
  { fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 92.60614675663679 },
  { fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.508066001283076 },
  { fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 72.27499816403673 },
  { fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 57.48997225382926 },
  { fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 57.40345634882333 },
  { fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 70.70814308763902 }
];

var fechas = {}; //el objeto de las fechas
// pongo las fechas distintas en el array de las fechas
for (var i in elarray) {
  fechas[elarray[i].fecha] = 0;
}

// estoy iterando elarray y sumo el valor correspondiente a la fecha
elarray.map(u => {
  fechas[u.fecha] += u.valor;
});

console.log(fechas);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) para lograr el objetivo esperado. Para contar con un indice único en el arreglo resultante, hice una concatenación entre los atributos `fecha` y `categoria` para poder ir sumando el valor entre registros.

Ejemplo:

```js
let arr=[{fecha:1433109600000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:49.73698235772901},{fecha:1433109600000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:60.49376144058218},{fecha:1433116800000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:28.505397876893902},{fecha:1433116800000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:74.91340610529366},{fecha:1433116800000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:43.71794096159791},{fecha:1433116800000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:23.395346314392796},{fecha:1433196000000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:31.881330330646218},{fecha:1433196000000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:87.31637095133911},{fecha:1433203200000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:46.300059172697175},{fecha:1433203200000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:38.82816133242129},{fecha:1433203200000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:28.03958217326741},{fecha:1433203200000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:59.82886035213437},{fecha:1433289600000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:11.327755968034303},{fecha:1433289600000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:6.400865852071913},{fecha:1433289600000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:67.31913706183693},{fecha:1433289600000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:92.60614675663679},{fecha:1433376000000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:43.508066001283076},{fecha:1433376000000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:72.27499816403673},{fecha:1433376000000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:57.48997225382926},{fecha:1433376000000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:57.40345634882333},{fecha:1433462400000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:70.70814308763902},{fecha:1433462400000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:0.3253988527121887},{fecha:1433462400000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:43.18931560611268},{fecha:1433462400000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:96.61915450438259},{fecha:1433548800000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:77.88148521586558},{fecha:1433548800000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:92.83072335206866},{fecha:1433548800000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:63.8569758442417},{fecha:1433548800000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:11.889180738447624},{fecha:1433635200000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:28.32219302898853},{fecha:1433635200000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:68.05799731426629},{fecha:1433635200000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:74.49832916690504},{fecha:1433635200000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:98.32817378920366},{fecha:1433721600000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:91.47337644564648},{fecha:1433721600000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:31.273994175467166},{fecha:1433721600000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:49.07981716102785},{fecha:1433721600000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:74.10101967551246},{fecha:1433808000000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:40.86583930566705},{fecha:1433808000000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:75.10236610849115},{fecha:1433808000000,categoria:"CAT 1",valor:92.7916625879253},{fecha:1433808000000,categoria:"CAT 2",valor:35.42493446978297},{fecha:1433894400000,categoria:"CAT 3",valor:94.65211432925513}]
var result = [];
arr.reduce(function (res, value) {
    if (!res[value.fecha + value.categoria]) {
        res[value.fecha + value.categoria] = {
            fecha: value.fecha,
            categoria: value.categoria,
            valor: value.valor
        };
        result.push(res[value.fecha + value.categoria])
    }
    else {
        res[value.fecha + value.categoria].valor += value.valor
    }
    return res;
}, {});

console.log('length de arr', arr.length);
console.log('length de resultado', result.length);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Con el siguiente codigo puedes probar. Según entendí tienes un arreglo de objetos donde algunas veces se repiten elementos que comparten la misma fecha y la misma categoria y lo que quieres hacer es cuando suceda esto es que aparezca solo 1 y que se vayan sumando sos valores. Basado en eso solo debes crear un nuevo arreglo vacio donde vas a ir almacenando los datos de la manera que deseabas y recorrer el original para cuando se cumpla esa condición no lo adicione sino que tome su valor y se lo incremente.

```
 //Arreglo original
 var data =  [{fecha: 1433109600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 49.73698235772901},
 {fecha: 1433109600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 60.49376144058218},
 {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 28.505397876893902},
 {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 74.91340610529366},
 {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.71794096159791},
 {fecha: 1433116800000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 23.395346314392796},
 {fecha: 1433196000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 31.881330330646218},
 {fecha: 1433196000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 87.31637095133911},
 {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 46.300059172697175},
 {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 38.82816133242129},
 {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 28.03958217326741},
 {fecha: 1433203200000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 59.82886035213437},
 {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 11.327755968034303},
 {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 6.400865852071913},
 {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 67.31913706183693},
 {fecha: 1433289600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 92.60614675663679},
 {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.508066001283076},
 {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 72.27499816403673},
 {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 57.48997225382926},
 {fecha: 1433376000000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 57.40345634882333},
 {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 70.70814308763902},
 {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 0.3253988527121887},
 {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 43.18931560611268},
 {fecha: 1433462400000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 96.61915450438259},
 {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 77.88148521586558},
 {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 92.83072335206866},
 {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 63.8569758442417},
 {fecha: 1433548800000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 11.889180738447624},
 {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 28.32219302898853},
 {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 68.05799731426629},
 {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 74.49832916690504},
 {fecha: 1433635200000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 98.32817378920366},
 {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 91.47337644564648},
 {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 31.273994175467166},
 {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 49.07981716102785},
 {fecha: 1433721600000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 74.10101967551246},
 {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 40.86583930566705},
 {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 75.10236610849115},
 {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 1", valor: 92.7916625879253},
 {fecha: 1433808000000, categoria: "CAT 2", valor: 35.42493446978297},
 {fecha: 1433894400000, categoria: "CAT 3", valor: 94.65211432925513}];

 //Nuevo arreglo
 var no_repeat = [];

 //Recorro el objeto original buscando repeticiones
 data.forEach(function(item, index){
      //Inicializo esta variable para cuando no se encuentren coincidencias en el arreglo nuevo lo añada por defecto
      var not_found = true;
      //Recorro el arreglo nuevo para ver si el elemento de la iteracion del arreglo original ya existe en el nuevo arreglo
      no_repeat.forEach(function(item2, index2){
        //En caso de que coincidan en fecha y categoria
        if(item.fecha == item2.fecha && item.categoria == item2.categoria){
           //Le sumo el valor al que traia
           no_repeat[index2].valor += item.valor;
           not_found = false;
        }
      });
      //Si no hay repetidos lo añado nuevo
      if(not_found){
        no_repeat.push(item);
  }
});

//Muestro los datos del arreglo nuevo
console.log(no_repeat);
```